# Nodejs Express Api Getting Undefined header only on Production

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, header, production

I have this auth middleware,

```
  const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.header("auth_token");
  console.log(req.header('auth_token'));

  if (!token || token==null) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "No token, authorization denied" });
  }else {
 ...
});
```

now this working fine on local host, but on **production** hosted with **nginx**
this code is not working , giving response as "**No token, authorization denied**"
and token getting as **undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nginx setup, you need to set the `proxy_pass_request_headers`, so that the proxy shall forward the headers to your backend server.

```
location / {
    ...
    proxy_pass_request_headers     on;
}
```

Second, if you need to have `_` in your header (like `auth_token` header), you need to enable that as well:

```
underscores_in_headers     on;
```

Or else, you need to use a header name without `_`.

Comment: it worked, only thing is i have to write this `underscores_in_headers on;` outside location block and inside server block